# Not able to get event of tableView didSelect

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have searched enough and tried everything I could but failed to get a solution.

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. The `textView` is `notEditable`. It's `scrolling enabled` property is set to `false` for `autoResizing`.

The `textView` is populated with an `attributedText` which is converted to `NSAttributedString` from a `html` and it has some `hyperlinks`. So I have set the `link` property of `data detector` as `true`, so that the `textView` can detect link taps.

Now the main problem is that I need to get the `didSelect` event of `tableView` to take user to a new screen, but I am not able to get the event because of `textView` link detection.

This is the code where I populate my `tableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdvertisementCell", for: indexPath) as! AdvertisementCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.setupCellData(model: advertiseMentModel!)
    return cell
}
```

Inside Cell sublclass:

```
func setupCellData(model : TSLatestDetailsModel) {
     if let desc = model.blurb_link {
     let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: desc.html2AttributedString!)
     attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 17)!], range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

    txtVwDesc.attributedText = attrString
    if !isSearchResults {
        txtVwDesc.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -5, bottom: -32.5, right: 0)
    } else {
        txtVwDesc.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    txtVwDesc.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: Constants.linkColor,


     NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor.rawValue : UIColor.clear,

     NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue : UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 17)!]

     layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}
```

Please suggest what is the best way solve the issue?

Comment: Simply show your code rather than mentioning it line by line. If you are using IB, show a screenshot of attributes.

Comment: I think you haven't understood the problem here, I have nothing to show to make you understand the problem. I have described everything that is required to understand the problem.

Comment: Trust me, you have everything in the code to make me understand your problem.

Comment: @Nitish: I have updated my question can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following: you have set the tableview delegate to self and user interaction is enabled for the cell, content view and text view and you have assigned the class to the tableView in the property inspector.

Comment: That's not the issue, the issue is when you tap on textView, the textviews tap event fires, e.g: it tries to copy text or detext link, do tableView's did select method does not get called.

Comment: Why don't you add a tap gesture to the text view and put the code from the tableView's didSelect into the handler for the textViewDidSelect?

Comment: What is `textViewDidSelect`? I have never heard of it.

Comment: It's not an iOS method it was just an example of a name you could use for your func, so call it every time the text view is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a UIview with clear background that covers the text you don't wanna be clickable. It will still detect your didSelectRow